# Why is Room query returning null if the item exists in the database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have inserted a Movie into my database and want to query the database based on the movieId. I can confirm that the movieId is in my database using the Stetho inspector. Why am I getting null?

DAO

```
@Dao
public interface MoviesDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void insertMovie(Movie movie);

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM movie WHERE id = :movieId ")
    LiveData<Movie> getMovie(long movieId);
```

ViewModel

```
    public void getMovieFromDatabase(Movie movie) {
        LiveData<Movie> result = movieRepository.getMovieFromDatabase(movie);
        Log.d(TAG, "result is: " + result.getValue());
    }
```

Repository

```
    public LiveData<Movie> getMovieFromDatabase(Movie movie) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Movie id: " + movie.getId());
        return dbInstance.moviesDao().getMovie(movie.getId());
    }
```

Result from Logcat

```
Movie id: 419704
result is: null
```

Image of database. Clearly movie id 419704 exists (second item):
[image]

Answer (score 4):

`getMovie()` is your DAO method. It returns a `LiveData`. That will cause Room to do the database I/O on a background thread.

However, you immediately attempt to get the value out of the `LiveData`. That will not work most of the time, as the background thread will not have completed its work yet.

Either:

- Get rid of the `LiveData` and have `getMovie()` return the results directly, and call `getMovie()` on a background thread, or
- `observe()` the `LiveData`, rather than attempt to use its value immediately